# git insists on user local user name on ubuntu while cloning

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, git, clone

I followed the [guides](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/setting-your-username-in-git) to set up my user name and e-mail. I then verified with the same commands.

```
git config --global user.name "<github user>"
git config --global user.name
> <github user>
```

However, when I run the git clone `git clone ssh://github.com/<github user>/<reponame>` then git tries my local user name:

```
Cloning into '<reponame>'...
<local user name>@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Why is this? Even the `cat ~/.gitconfig` looks as it should.

Answer (score 1):

Your [Git username](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-username) which is used by [Git](https://git-scm.com) to identify the [author and committer](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#_commit_information) of a commit has nothing to do with your [SSH login name used by SSH](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#l), nor [does it have anything to do](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/setting-your-username-in-git) with your [GitHub account](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/signing-up-for-github/signing-up-for-a-new-github-account).

SSH always uses your local login as the remote login if you don't tell it which login to use.

You can either use

```sh
git clone ssh://git@github.com/<github account>/<repository>
```

or just

```sh
git clone git@github.com/<github account>/<repository>
```

which is, by the way, what GitHub tells you to use when you go to a repository and click on "Code", "Local", "Clone", and "SSH":

[image: GitHub screenshot showing clone dialog with the SSH URI]

Alternatively, you can set the SSH login name for GitHub (which is always `git`) in your [SSH configuration file](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config.5#User), which is what I do:

```
Host github.com
   User git
```

In fact, in my case, I have two different GitHub accounts, one for work and one for my personal stuff, which means I use two different SSH keys. I also often use networks where SSH on port 22 is blocked, so I use the [alternative SSH service running on `ssh.github.com:443`](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/using-ssh-over-the-https-port). So, my SSH config looks something like this:

```
# Personal GitHub account
Host github.com-personal
   HostName ssh.github.com
   Port 443
   User git
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_personal

# Work GitHub account
Host github.com-work
   HostName ssh.github.com
   Port 443
   User git
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_work
```

So, in my case, I would use

```sh
git clone github.com-personal/<github user>/<reponame>
```

or

```sh
git clone github.com-work/<github user>/<reponame>
```

depending on whether I am using my personal or my work account.

Unfortunately, I have discovered a small inconvenience with this solution: some GitHub clients, for example, the [GitHub Pull Requests and Issues](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GitHub.vscode-pull-request-github) extension for [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), do not use the SSH config to resolve repository URIs. They assume that if the hostname in the Git SSH URI is `github.com-personal`, then they can also interact with the GitHub HTTP ReST JSON API at that hostname, which is not the case. So, every time I open one of my projects in Visual Studio Code, I get an error message from the GitHub Pull Requests and Issues extension telling me that it could not load the PRs and issues.

Alternatively, it should also work to set the [`credential.username`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials#Documentation/gitcredentials.txt-username) configuration parameter:

```sh
git config credential.username git
```

Which will use `git` for all URIs if you don't specify the username in the URI itself. Or, you can be more specific with something like this:

```sh
git config credential.ssh://github.com/.username git
```

I would also set up my Git username and Git email for the repository as appropriate, i.e. either

```sh
git config user.name 'Jörg W Mittag'
git config user.email personal-email@example.com
```

or

```sh
git config user.name 'Jörg Mittag (Company Name)'
git config user.email work-email@example.com
```

I am not using [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/) or the [GitHub CLI](https://cli.github.com/) tool, but I still out of habit also set the GitHub account:

```sh
git config github.user <personal github account>
```

or

```sh
git config github.user <work github account>
```

By the way, fundamentally, it seems you are confused about what the different names mean, so here is a quick refresher:

- *Git Committer Name* (`GIT_COMMITTER_NAME` / `committer.name`): the human-readable name of the person who makes the commit; this should *not* be a username, it should be the name by which people address you personally.
- *Git Committer Email* (`GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL` / `committer.email`): the email address of the person who makes the commit.
- *Git Author Name* (`GIT_AUTHOR_NAME` / `author.name`): the human-readable name of the person who *authored the changes* in the commit; this should *not* be a username, it should be the name by which people address you personally. Usually, this is the same as the Committer Name, but they can be different e.g. in the case where person A commits code sent to them via email from person B.
- *Git Author Email* (`GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL` / `author.email`): the email address of the person who *authored the changes* in the commit. Usually, this is the same as the Committer Email, but they can be different e.g. in the case where person A commits code sent to them via email from person B.
- *Git User Name* (`user.name`): used as the default for both Committer Name and Author Name; this should *not* be a username, it should be the name by which people address you personally.
- *Git User Email* (`EMAIL` / `user.email`): used as the default for both Committer Email and Author Email.
- *Login used for the transport connection* (`credential.username`): used as the username for HTTPS authentication or the login for SSH authentication. In the case of GitHub, the username for HTTPS authentication is your GitHub account, whereas the login for SSH authentication is always `git`. This is most often passed as part of the repository URI, not as a configuration option.
- *GitHub account* (can be configured as part of the Git configuration in `github.user`, but is completely ignored by Git): the GitHub account is completely irrelevant to both Git and SSH. The entire `github.*` section in a Git configuration file is ignored by Git. This is only used by GitHub-specific tools such as GitHub Desktop or GitHub CLI.